# how can i find total number of pixels in 24bit rgb color model

Tags: multimedia

24 bits RGB color model with 2048 pixels in width and 1536 pixels in
height has a total of 3.1 megapixels is correct if that so how to get this answer. I am totally new to multimedia section

Answer (score 0):

```
Total Pixels = [Pixel width * Pixel height * color depth * #frames per seconds]
 = [2048 * 1536 * (24/8)]/1024 * 1024
 = 9 Megapixel
```

Comment: I contact on of my mater in Multimedia and sorted the problem